# Could not load the "TweetSheetLocationArrow.png" image... Twitter/Social Framework for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, twitter

I am using Twitter and Social framework in my app for iOS. I have been using the same frameworks for days now without any issues. However, today when I run the app in the simulator (haven't changed any Twitter or Social specific code), I get the following error as I try to send a tweet from my app:

```
Could not load the "TweetSheetLocationArrow.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.apple.sociald.Social"
```

Any idea what's this problem is related to and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tweet sheet wants the resource "TweetSheetLocationArrw.png" at runtime from a nib bundle with the bundle identifier specified ( if that doesn't mean anything to you google "apple bundle programming guide" ) and it is either unable to read the resource, or the resource no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

Ignore it. It's a missing image asset in the device simulator and is harmless.